# NRefactory has missing dlls

Tags: c#, vb.net, compiler-construction, mono, mono.cecil

Heys all, I've tried to use NRefactory(Vb) https://github.com/icsharpcode/NRefactory/ but it didn't come with mono.cecil.dll so i downloaded that too, but when i merged it together the versions seem 
to be off (i had error Mono.Collections missing class)

does anyone seem to be able to get NRefactory working?

Edit:
btw i've changed to Mono.Cecil 0.9.4. However when i try to build ICSharpCode.NRefactory i had some errors:

> ```
> Error 6   'Mono.Cecil.PInvokeInfo' does not contain a definition for
> ```
>
> 'IsBestFitDisabled' and no extension
>   method 'IsBestFitDisabled' accepting a
>   first argument of type
>   'Mono.Cecil.PInvokeInfo' could be
>   found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\Test\NRefactory\ICSharpCode.NRefactory\TypeSystem\CecilLoader.cs    376 14  ICSharpCode.NRefactory
>       post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the new Version the Method IsBestFitDisabled now is called: IsBestFistDisabled 
The got an extra "s" inside... :)

Comment: i thought you were joking.. what does `IsBestFistDisabled` means anyway? shouldn't it have had been `IsBestFitDisabled`?

Comment: @Pacerier: IsBestFistDisabled was a typo in Cecil 0.9.4. NRefactory was using a pre-release version of Cecil 0.9.5 which has that typo fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Did you make sure to get Mono.Cecil 0.9.4 as mentioned on the GitHub page?

It has a different API than the previous Mono.Cecil 0.6.9.

Comment: btw i've changed to Mono.Cecil 0.9.4. However when i try to build i had some errors (see my edited post)